# Jiles Atherton magnetic model for iron powder cores

Tags: magnetics, iron-core

I am currently designing several SMPS in LTspice.
I am using the excellent work of Mr Bordodynov to model ferrite transformers. The Bordodynov Ltspice examples include a dataset for the JA model for several ferrite cores. (magmod.txt). I have even found a larger JA model dataset in the standard Pspice library (magnetic.lib). However, even this library is limited to the Philips and Ferroxcube cores, which if I am not mistaken, are only ferrites, not low permeability iron powder materials.

It seems that computing the JA model parameters requires only a BH curve plot, but these are also difficult to find.

Has anyone has an idea on where to search ?

Comment: I've had some luck requesting this info from distributors.  But there is no master-list that I am aware of.  Would be nice though (and horrible to maintain.)

Comment: thank you. i had posted an old draft where my question was ambiguous. sorry.

Comment: Well, I was a little bit mistaken. it seems that Ferroxcube 2Pxx materials are iron powder. xx being the relative permeability. So the dataset is not devoid of any info about iron powder as I first thought.

Comment: Without checking now, my past experience as a satisfied Micrometals customer (with no other links to them) leads me to expect that Micrometals would be able to help - either by having data on their cores already available or perhaps providing it on request. I was only a customer and only buying at modest commercial volumes, but I was very impressed by their service.

Comment: @rodv92 https://www.micrometals.com/products/materials/